# Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'tabs/tab1/discover/a1'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-routing

Can anyone help me with this? I feel like my tabs-routing page isn't set up properly but any time I try fixing it, it just breaks even more.

I created an ionic angular tabs app. I have data stored locally which is shown in a card display on the Discover page. After clicking on a card I want to be brought to that cards main page but the error shown below is what I get.

[image: This is the full error I have]

App-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'places', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'auth', loadChildren: () => import('./auth/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthPageModule) },
  {
    path: 'places',
    loadChildren: () => import('./places/places.module').then(m => m.PlacesPageModule),
    canLoad: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'bookings',
    loadChildren: () => import('./bookings/bookings.module').then(m => m.BookingsPageModule),
    canLoad: [AuthGuard]
  }
];
```

tabs-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'tab1',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
        loadChildren: () => import('../tab1/tab1.module').then(m => m.Tab1PageModule)
      },
      {
        path: ':artistId',
        loadChildren: () => import('../tab1/discover/artist-details/artist-details.module').then(m => m.ArtistDetailsPageModule)
      },
      {
        path: ':venueId',
        loadChildren: () => import('../tab1/discover/venue-details/venue-details.module').then(m => m.VenueDetailsPageModule)
      }
    ]
  },
```

Discover.page.html:

```
<ion-content class="ion-padding">
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col size="12" size-sm="8" offset-sm="2">
        <ion-card
          fill="clear"
          [routerLink]="['/','tabs','tab1','discover',loadedArtist[0].id]"
        >
          <ion-card-header>
            <ion-card-title>{{ loadedArtist[0].name }}</ion-card-title>
            <ion-card-subtitle
              >{{ loadedArtist[0].cost | currency }} / Night</ion-card-subtitle
            >
          </ion-card-header>
          <ion-img [src]="loadedArtist[0].imageUrl"></ion-img>
          <ion-card-content>
            <p>Rating: {{ loadedArtist[0].rating | percent}}</p>
            <p>Genre: {{ loadedArtist[0].genre }}</p>
            <p>Equipment: {{ loadedArtist[0].equipment }}</p>
          </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col size="12" size-sm="8" offset-sm="2">
        <ion-card
          *ngFor="let artist of loadedArtist.slice(1)"
          fill="clear"
          [routerLink]="['/','tabs','tab1','discover',artist.id]"
        >
          <ion-card-header>
            <ion-card-title>{{ artist.name }}</ion-card-title>
            <ion-card-subtitle
              >{{ artist.cost | currency }} / Night</ion-card-subtitle
            >
          </ion-card-header>
          <ion-img [src]="artist.imageUrl"></ion-img>
          <ion-card-content>
            <p>Rating: {{ artist.rating | percent}}</p>
            <p>Genre: {{ artist.genre }}</p>
            <p>Equipment: {{ artist.equipment }}</p>
          </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row></ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The route path needs to be constructed correctly. Try changing:

```
      {
        path: ':artistId',
        loadChildren: () => import('../tab1/discover/artist-details/artist-details.module').then(m => m.ArtistDetailsPageModule)
      },
```

to

```
      {
        path: 'discover/:artistId',
        loadChildren: () => import('../tab1/discover/artist-details/artist-details.module').then(m => m.ArtistDetailsPageModule)
      },
```